# Subsetting 2D numpy arrays methods difference

Tags: numpy, 2d, subset

I am super new to python and/or programming (first question here and I hope I'm doing it right) and subsetting 2D numpy has gotten me puzzled in a specific case:
I have the following:

```
print(np_baseball)

[[180.   78.4]
 [215.  102.7]
 [210.   98.5]
 [188.   75.2]]
```

If I try to subset like this, they are the same: first row, first column

```
np_baseball[0][1]
78.4
np_baseball[0,1]
78.4
```

Or first row, second column

```
np_baseball[0][0]
180.0
np_baseball[0,0]
180.0
```

When I try whole rows it is okay: second row, all columns (all elements of the second row)

```
np_baseball[1][:]
array([215. , 102.7])
np_baseball[1,:]
array([215. , 102.7])
```

But when I try to select a whole column the methods behave different:

```
np_baseball[:][0]
array([180. ,  78.4])
np_baseball[:,0]
array([180., 215., 210., 188.])
```

By fiddling I've come to understand that a `2d_numpy[:]` is selecting the whole numpy and even if a type a second [:] as if trying to then select its rows it just behave as before, selecting the whole 2d numpy. Why is that? And is there a way to select whole columns the the [ ][ ] method?

Thank you

Comment: `np_baseball[:][0]` means: at first `np_baseball[:]` and then getting the first index of that i.e. `[0]`. For getting access to a specified part of a numpy array, it is recommended to use slicing styles such as `np_baseball[:,0]` to address that.

Comment: Understand `x[a][b]` as `x[a]` first, followed the [b] indexing.  Two separate indexing operations, not a joint (2d) one.